# Why is php rename() corrupting my file?

Tags: php, rename, plupload

I am using plupload to do an upload of multiple files to my server. Using this, there is a parameter 'url : 'upload.php'. upload.php catches the files as they are received, and might recombine them if they get chunked. Once the full file is received, it sends a response back to the original page, displaying a green checkbox icon.

I have added some code to this page, after all the main code to manipulate the photos I have uploaded. My plan is to create three copies of my full size image, lg, med, and small. I got this part working, but then decided to first rename the original file to match my naming scheme.

I now get a corrupted renamed file, and thus my three smaller images also get corrupted.

```
//get the original file info
$filepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
$filepathinfo = pathinfo($filepath.$fileName);//fileName is used previously in the file

//rename original file to a unique name
$finding_id = 'xyz';
$file_name_new = uniqid($client_id . '-' . $finding_id . '-', true); //doesn't include extension
//rename($filepath.$fileName, $filepath.$file_name_new.'.'.$ext);
//copy($filepath.$fileName, $filepath.$file_name_new.'.'.$ext);
```

As is, I get my one file, or how ever many I uploaded, byte size matches original exactly, and name stays the same (except for removal of certain characters).

If I uncomment only the rename function, I actually get two files. The byte sizes total the original photo. The larger file displays with a section of gray at the bottom. The smaller file doesn't display at all.

If I uncomment only the copy function, I get an exact renamed copy of my original file, my original file, and another file, the same size and corruption as the larger file doing a rename.

Any ideas? Seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Was the process that uploaded the file complete? Was the file descriptor closed? All the buffers were flushed?

Comment: According to this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159431/php-change-file-extension, a workaround is to use copy.  Still, it shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Horus - I tried copy, but got just as weird of results. There must be something going on with this Pluploader, which I have never used before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot I had the chunking feature turned on. Must have turned it on to test something. For whatever reason, when the script was running the last chunk of the file hadn't been fully appended yet. Thanks for all the input anyway!

Answer (score 4):

1. if the file was currently uploaded by HTTP POST use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
2. if you fopen() somewhere in this request the same file make sure to call fclose()

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing to the file yourself?  If so, the problem might be that you're missing a call to `fflush` or `fclose`.  (The last chunk of the file not getting written and the file no longer being there when PHP gets round to writing it.  This shouldn't happen if you're using Linux or some other Unix, but I could envisage it on Windows.)

Comment: Nope, not doing any writing to the file of my own. Just letting the plupload handle that. As far as I can tell that file is using fclose appropriately.