# php rename() breaks image

Tags: php, image, rename

I'm trying to move images from one folder to another. I'm using the following code:

```
rename("/public_html/wp-content/uploads/image.png","/public_html/wp-content/uploads/folder/image.png");
```

The image gets moved fine to the new folder and the new path is accessible, only the image breaks. It gets a file size of 0.01k and shows the broken image icon.

I'm using the same rename function for files and folders and everything gets moved without any problems. What could be the problem for the images?

EDIT: The problem only seems to occur when the code gets fired from an ajax request. If I load the same code directly it works fine. If it gets loaded from ajax the image breaks.

Comment: if you check the folder, does the file actually exist in the new folder?  what is the permissions of the `../uploads/folder` directory?

Comment: what is the other code for image upload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is php rename() corrupting my file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904304/why-is-php-rename-corrupting-my-file)

Comment: check the folder permission.

Comment: how about using an absolute path? like `home/public_html/path/to/image`?

Comment: @Clayton yes, the file exists in the new folder. folder permission is 755.

Comment: @roullie updated the path, I'm actually using the absolute path.

Comment: @rahul I'm not uploading images. The images are already on the server (they have been uploaded before). I just need to move them to another folder.

Comment: Sounds like an issue either with the mime type (content-type) or the content-size being off. Have you checked the browser's Network activity in the dev tools to confirm if the broken images are a result of a 404 or some other HTTP error? Can you open the image in the browser by navigating directly to its URL (versus having it be part of an HTML document)? Have you followed up on the other question that @NijrajGelani linked above? The OP on that question figured out that it was due to Chunking being enabled. Is it enabled on your HTTP server?

Comment: can you please add your image link or sample

Comment: Also, to be sure it has been asked, are you sure that the image isn't broken because the HTML or the CMS is still pointing to the old image location (instead of the "/folder/" sub-folder)?

Comment: @Anthony yes, the file exists and is accessible from the new path. If I check it on the server directly it has been moved to the new folder but the file size has been changed to 0.01k and if I try to open it I get the message that the image is broken/unreadable.

Comment: You mean open it on the server directly via a web browser? And it returns an HTTP 200 response code but just a .01k file? Have you verified if the image can be downloaded/opened correctly via other protocols, like FTP? What evidence do you have that the file at the new location is actually intact and was moved correctly (versus `rename` just doing a touch with the new path and filename so that there is no actual data in the file)?

Comment: If you use copy() instead of rename() does that work?

Comment: To reiterate, I'm not asking "is there a file located at that location with the correct permissions", I'm asking "is the file that is at that location actually a .01k file with no real data, so that it really is a broken image file"?

Comment: @maxhb copy does exactly the same. In that case the original images stays ok, the new image gets added but is broken.

Comment: @Anthony exactly, the file returns no errors. It shows fine only it's just a small .01k without any data.